# How do I send a 2D array from jquery to php?

Tags: ajax, json, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array which I want to send to a php page with $.ajax.

This is the code which creates the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i<rowlen; i++) {
                           if (breakcheck) {
                              break;
                           }
                           for (var j = 0; j<=columnlen; j++) {
                              thtext = columnheads.eq(j).text();
                              current_td = $(newrows[i]).find("td").eq(j);

                              if (current_td.find("input").length >0) {
                                 rowdata[i,thtext] = current_td.find("input").val().trim();
                                 if (rowdata[i,thtext] =='') {
                                    alert("You must complete all fields");
                                    breakcheck = true;
                                    break;
                                 }
                              } else {
                                 rowdata[i,thtext] ='nada';
                              }
                           }//inner loop
                        }//outer loop
```

The array is filled properly with the nested loops and the I use JSON.stringify to format it. However when the ajax call is made all that is sent is an empty object ([]). What's wrong?

Comment: I might be wrong, but arr[i,j] is not the way to use multidimension arrays in C-style languages. That would be arr[i][j]

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but `arr[i,j]` is not the way to use multidimensional arrays in C-style languages. That would be `arr[i][j]`.

IMHO what `arr[i,j]` will do is function as [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Comma_Operator) and use only j as an index.

Answer (score 1):

OK I solved this by declaring r as an object (var r = {}) instead of declaring it as an array (var r = []). Thanks for the help.

Comment: this should be in the original question.